# Manipular url com javascript

Tags: javascript, html, redirecionamento

Possuo um blog e migrei de plataforma (Blogger -> Wordpress) sendo que também mudei o domínio. Para os artigos mais novos não enfrento problema algum, no entanto artigos com mais de um ou dois anos, existem links espalhados pela web com o domínio antigo.

Eu preciso manipular a URL da seguinte maneira:

Quando o usuário acessar o link, por exemplo:

http://www.site1.com/2015/05/artigo_a

Lhe é exibido uma mensagem dizendo que o blog mudou de endereço e um link é gerado conforme a URL da página ativa (prefiro isso do que redirecionar automaticamente o usuário, no entanto, não descarto esta solução) :

http://www.site2.com/2015/05/artigo_a

O domínio é diferente, no entanto a estrutura da URL é a mesma em ambas as plataformas.

Li alguns tutoriais acerca disso com PHP, no entanto, no Blogger eu posso trabalhar apenas com HTML e javascript.

Comment: O dominio antigo está em teu nome? tens acesso a ele?

Comment: Sim @Sergio, é um domínio ".blogspot.com", o domínio novo é ".blog.br"

Comment: Acho que seria melhor fazer esse redirecionamento onde tens o dominio registado. Um "forward" simples.

Comment: Acontece que o primeiro domínio (antigo) está nos servidores do Google e o segundo (novo) está em um servidor que eu contratei e, neste caso, eu só consigo redirecionar os domínios registrados neste servidor.

Comment: Qual é o produto/serviço do Google que tinhas contratado? Não podes transferir o dominio? ou simplesmente telo parqueado e fazer forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vai aqui um exemplo>>

```
<script> 
var ok = window.location.pathname; 
window.open('http://linkdowebsitenovo.com/' +ok +window.location.search, target="_self");
document.write('<center><p><h4>O Website Movido.<p>Redirecionando</p><p>Caso não seja redirecionado automáticamente </h4><h2><br><a href="" onclick="javascript:window.location="http://linkdowebsitenovo.com'+ window.location.pathname +' '+ window.location.search +'">Clique aqui.</a></p></h2></br>');
</script>
```

Espero que tenha sido útil. :)
[Não consegui saber ao certo o que você quer fazer..]

Comment: Esta resposta implica ter 2 sites online quando o redirect devia ser feito via em nível anterior. Redirect do dominio, ou menos mau no htaccess, um pouco pior no PHP e um pouco pior ainda já no HTML na `head` com `meta`tags. Fazer assim no JavaScript (acho eu) que é a pior solução. Até porque os motores de busca não vão ter o código do `redirect`

Comment: (y) _Sim, Mais estava respondendo o que ele pediu, Como você disse, Realmente é um dos piores métodos, Mais como o blogspot é muito limitado, Pode ser até um bom método._

Comment: A sua resposta é válida. Comentei para o utilizador ter mais informação.. Vou continuar a perguntar mais informação para termos mais dados sobre o serviço que ele tem e ver se há outra opção.

Comment: Obrigado, Sergio e Mega, pelas informações e conhecimento transmitido. A solução apresentada por Mega funcionou e, embora não seja a melhor solução, é a melhor para o Blogger. Obrigado